Ubuntu fails to mount Fairphone 4
My Ubuntu system (22.04.05 LTS) fails to mount my Fairphone 4 on my machine, A Dell Vostro 5468 (16Gb memory). Any ideas on how to resolve this? I'd intended to copy my Rhythmbox music onto this device ready for it to be a Xmas present for my wife.
Error messages:
Unable to open MTP device "001,005"
Files hangs at the error message:
Unable to access Fairphone 4 5G
Separately this message:
Failed to mount fairphone 4 5G
Any ideas?

A phone is not attached storage. A phone is a complete computer pretending to be attached storage when so set. Please edit the question to confirm that you set the phone properly.

"Did you set the phone properly by doing ............." would be considerably more helpful.

If you are asking for the process to set your Fairphone to accept MTP connections, that seems an appropriate question for Fairphone support more than Ubuntu support.

I glean "A phone needs to be set to accept MTP connections - have you done this? I don't know how your phone does this but why not try Fairphone support?"  We got there! thanks.
